# Libreoffice-templates package - how do I access them?

Tags: libreoffice, templates

I have installed the package `libreoffice-templates` via Synaptic, but when I go into LibreOffice Writer and open Template manager, there are no templates there (for Writer) - Is there something I need to do to import the templates in the package into the Template manager?

Answer (score 1):

The template files are installed to:

```
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/template/
```

However, there seem to be only a handful of Impress templates, and not one Writer template.

Source: http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/all/libreoffice-templates/filelist

(You can change "quantal" in the above address with "raring" if your release is 13.04).